# How to create a tkinter error message box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, pyinstaller

I am wanting to create a simple message box in Tkinter that appears and displays the exact error message.  Could anyone direct me to how this might be 
 achieved in tkinter, I have not been able to find much on this topic.

E.g:

```
traceback.format_exc().replace(':', '-')
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Error", "Have you checked your fridge?"d, 1)
                                                             ^
#'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

I am wanting to add this with pyinstaller.  I suppose pyinstaller creates a text file and you can see in cmd before it closes, but it would be nice if a message box appear with exact traceerror.

Answer (score 17):

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showerror("Title", "Message")
```

check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#module-tkinter.messagebox) for more info

Answer (score 2):

This login system which will pop up messagebox when you provide wrong data for entry `messagebox` should be entered into the entry if not the messagebox will pop up prompting you an error as occured

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def top():
    if entry1.get() == "messagebox":
       log.destroy()
       root.deiconify()
    else:
       messagebox.showerror("error", "try again")
       messagebox.showinfo("my message","this is an example of showinfo\nmessagebox")
       messagebox.showwarning("warning", "show warning example in tkinter" ) 


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

log = Toplevel(root)
log.geometry("200x200")


label1 = Label(log, text="password")
entry1 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="login", command=top)

label1.pack()
entry1.pack()
button1.pack(side="bottom")

lab = Label(root, text="welcome bro").pack()


root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```